# Excel VBA - How to search for duplicate values in a column and append _count

Tags: vba, excel

I've a column with values like- INC0001, INC0002 etc. I need to find duplicate values and append _count to them without using 2 For loops.
For ex. for following data-
INC001
INC002
INC003
INC001
INC002
INC001
The output should be
INC001
INC002
INC003
INC001_1
INC002_1
INC001_2
.

I have done it using 2 for loops however it takes about 15-20 minutes for about 15000 records. Any more efficient way of doing it in excel macro?
**Existing Code**

```
    Sub AppendMacro()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Dim lngMaxRow As Long
    lngMaxRow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim count As Integer
    For i = 2 To lngMaxRow - 1 Step 1
    Dim incNum As String
    incNum = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
    count = 1
    If (Len(incNum) = 11) Then
        For j = i + 1 To lngMaxRow Step 1
        If (incNum = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & j).Value) Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("A" & j).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & j).Value & "_" & count
            count = count + 1
        End If
        Next
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you have existing code then including it in your question may prevent it from being closed.  I would suggest maybe using a dictionary for this - use the values for the key and store the instance number as the value. You only need a single loop.

Comment: Can you first sort the data? If so, it'll make the VBA easier, and perhaps you could even just use a formula instead of requiring VBA.

Comment: Using step by step forumla application you can solve without writing VBA
1. Copy data to a new col
2. Remove duplicates
3. use COUNTIF to calculate occurrences
4. Appent count to the key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could go like this:

```
Sub AppendMacro()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
            For Each cell In .Cells
                cell.Value = cell.Value & "_" & WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Parent.Range(.Cells(1), cell), cell.Value & "_*")
            Next
            .Replace what:="_0", replacement:="", lookat:=xlPart
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.Thankyou very  much! :)